# Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited. Use user.set() instead

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a project where user is able to register an account using referral code. During the process of a user registering an account, this error occur.
"Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited. Use user.set() instead."
What should be the cause of this error message?

Note: I'm using Django UserCreationForm

[image]

Views.py

```
def RefSignupView(request):
    profile_id = request.session.get('ref_profile')
    print('profile.id', profile_id)
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        if profile_id is not None:
            recommended_by_profile = Profile.objects.get(id=profile_id)

            instance = form.save() #The error points to instance=form.save()
            registered_user = User.objects.get(id=instance.id)
            registered_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=registered_user)
            registered_profile.recommended_by = recommended_by_profile.user
            registered_profile.save()
        else:
            form.save()
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')

        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('site:profile', username=username)
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'ref_signup.html', context)
```

Models.py

```
GENDER = (
    ('male', 'male'),
    ('female', 'female'),
    )

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True) 
    code = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True)
    recommended_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="ref_by", blank=True, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='ProfilePicture/', default="ProfilePicture/avatar.png", blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=GENDER, verbose_name="gender", blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null= True) 
    is_online = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Profile'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Profiles'
        ordering = ['-date']

    '''Method to filter database results'''
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username}-{self.code}"
```

Comment: Share the related models.

Comment: I'm using django default UserCreationForm from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

Comment: Share the `Profile` model.

Comment: @Marco I have shared the Profile Model in question